# Android RealViewSwticher problem

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

Many of you know, that there's is a class RealViewSwticher created by Marc Reichelt http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010_09_01_archive.html

If someone used or uses this thing, please can you help me.

Here's my .xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >           
        <de.marcreichelt.android.RealViewSwitcher
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/real_view_switcher">    
        <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView>      
        <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView>
        </de.marcreichelt.android.RealViewSwitcher> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my main class.

```
public class MyMain extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RealViewSwitcher realViewSwitcher = (RealViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.real_view_switcher);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        GridView gridview2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridview2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        realViewSwitcher.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);
    }

    private final RealViewSwitcher.OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener = new RealViewSwitcher.OnScreenSwitchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScreenSwitched(int screen) {
            // this method is executed if a screen has been activated, i.e. the screen is completely visible
            //  and the animation has stopped (might be useful for removing / adding new views)
            Log.d("RealViewSwitcher", "switched to screen: " + screen);
        }
};
    }
```

I really don't understand what i am doing wrong, in the Example there's comment how to use it in xml:

```
    // note that you can also define your own views directly in a resource XML, too by using:
    // <de.marcreichelt.android.RealViewSwitcher
    //     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    //     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    //     android:id="@+id/real_view_switcher">
    //         <!-- your views here -->
    // </de.marcreichelt.android.RealViewSwitcher>
```

The problem is: It is not working. I can see only my main GridView and i can't scroll to the second. If soemeone knews how where i made a mistake or if someone knews another way to do a real scrolling between views, please answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use ScrollView? Try to use something like this:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="110px">
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/grds"
      android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
        <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView>      
        <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView>

      </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

if it does't work, looak at this post

[Switching between two GridViews in the same Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781334/switching-between-two-gridviews-in-the-same-activity)

Comment: I need an animation like the animation when changing screen in the android launcher. I tried to paly with Scroll VIew and Horizontal Scroll VIew, and I seem it's not what i need, or i am not doing thing right.